# Einstein/Tableau CRM Date range binding filter by previous

Tags: einstein-analytics, einstein, tableau-crm

I have a requirement where I'm using a Date widget as a binding to filter a table column.

I'm using binding {{row(Close_Date_1.selection, [0], ["min", "max"]).asDateRange("date('Close_Date_Year', 'Close_Date_Month', 'Close_Date_Day')")}};

[image]

However, I need to also automatically use that date to be a previous year filter on another column, is there a way to use and filter from same Date widget automatically by previous year?

I've tried having 2 separate date widgets and binding for each but I'm told this is not a good user experience.

Answer (score 0):

Found the way to do it from this blog:

https://www.salesforceblogger.com/2022/03/03/one-date-widget-two-date-filters-plus-an-offset/